# Как понять пространства имен никак не связаны ни с модулями,ни со сборками

Tags: c#, .net, сборка, namespace

Их ничего не связывает потому что пространство имен не имеет физического представления,а всего лишь условность,которая объединяет множество классов или что?

Comment: Путь к классу в пространстве имен, это как путь к файлу в каталоге, с одной лишь разницей, класс может быть объявлен невидимым или видимым для всего что за пределами его пространства имен. Это все проверяется на этапе компиляции. Так что не только в объединяющей условности дело.

Comment: Путь к классу,Вы имеете в виду полное имя класса?

Comment: Можно и так сказать.

Comment: @aepot ,хах, простите,не совсем понял получается это верно,что пространство имен не связан со сборкой потому что не имеет физического представления?:|

Comment: Что такое по-вашему физическое представление? В плане ООП? В плане ООП даже класс не имеет физического представления, только объект имеет, или что вы имеете в виду? Генерируется ли какой-то код для класса в IL? Конечно да, иначе как будет создан объект, для неймспейса - то что информация о неймспейсах содерхитс в сборке - факт, а вот используется ли она в рантайме, ну если только для рефлексии.